# Assign super key to shortcut

Tags: gnome, gnome-classic, gnome-do

I am using gnome classic (no effects) on Ubuntu 11.10.
I installed gnome-do today, and I wanted to assign it to the <kbd>Super</kbd> key. However I can only assign it to a combination of keys (<kbd>Super</kbd> + some other key).
Does anyone know a way to work around this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is a code limitation - handling *just* modifier keys is different to handling a key combination including modifiers, and I didn't think that anyone would want to use just <kbd>Super</kbd> as the summon key.

You also end up with odd problems like Unity (and GNOME Shell) is having, where *only* Unity gets keypresses which contain <kbd>Super</kbd>.

It'd be possible to implement modifier-only keybindings, but I'm not sure how much effort it would be. I'd accept a clean merge request or patch implementing this, but I'm not planning on implementing this myself in the near future.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/do/+bug/1093004